# Solid state disks in new Apples

Tags: hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

Looking at the news of Apple integrating the Solid state disks onto its motherboard in the new light and crispy version of its mac, was wondering is this a good idea, and what has changed to make this dramatic decision for not using a daughter board.

I know about the problems with NOR and NAND flash, I done the research on that, but was wondering, does apple know something I don't about the reliability?

Have they done anything to the OS to prevent too many writes?

I currently use USB Thumb disks for OS's and know the problems of this, I tend to use specialized OS stuff to prevent too many writes. So Far none of my productions boxes have failed (1 year 8 months) and if they do I just replace the USB disk with another copy of the USB and throw the broken one away.

If the Solid state chips are soldered/attached to the main board, will this cause problems as there is a definite difference from an OS designed with Solid State and ones without.

Have Apple come up with something really innovative in the State disks and am I missing something?

Comment: cue apple hatred. Personally, I'm thinking they've gone with SSD because its reached the exact point in its life cycle at which  people who will pay several times over the odds for hardware think its cool enough to get excited about.

Comment: I be honest, I looked at the Thin and crispy 11" apple special and got really excited, especially at £850. Then I took a look at the integrated SD and thought, oh my, thats going to cause me problems. Would love to buy one, but is it just a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: really ? - i have a dual 1.8ghz laptop with 4 gb of ram that cost £260 new a year ago ;-/ Ok its not tiny and light, but i could get one for every mamber of my family for one of those things.

Comment: You got to see one of those thin and crispies. They are quite something. The cost is an issue but I can write that off as a business expense. The only issue I got with macs is the sealed nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not missing anything, and your scepticism is rightly placed.

You can [see in the teardown page](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook-Air-11-Inch-Model-A1370-Teardown/3745/1) that **the SSD is actually a separate board** in the laptop. It's custom-made for Apple, so you probably won't see easy customer-side replacements, but the fact remains that the SSD can be replaced.

Because the SSD **can** be replaced, your concern is addressed and not a problem - in theory. In reality, it won't be as easy as your method of just swapping one USB disk for another, though.

Comment: Thanks. Damn thats a nice piece of architecture. Those screws look a bit tricky, but no doubt someone will get hold of the drives. Need more time to think about this. I don't usually go for macs at all but the 11 inch model looks perfect, much better than my Acer One! :) Still might wipe the thing out and install Puppy Linux on it or something just for the hell of it.

Comment: Yep, easily replaceable for the warranty issues that are bound to crop up.  Other than that, I've found that the typical Mac users tend to upgrade a LOT faster than typical PC users.  Not much concern about long-term failures when it'll be in a closet somewhere after a year or 2 anyways.